# Need to get variable name and its data from json file C#

Tags: c#, json

Example of Json:

```
{
"typeOfDriver": "selenium",
"goToURL": "url",
}
```

Basically I need a way to gather the first variable name "typeOfDriver", with the code I'm using right now I just get the data from the element.

Code:

```
dynamic loadConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(path + "/" + response));

string typeOfDriver = loadConfig["typeOfDriver"];
```

Thanks!

Edit: Explained better, I need to know the first line variable name, for example this time is typeOfDriver, another time will be another so I need to know it.

Comment: Did you try doing `string typeOfDriver = loadConfig.typeOfDriver`?

Comment: after your edit, i think @PavelAnikhouski answer will solve your problem? if not, so can you explain more!

Comment: Hi @Sajid, if I'm not wrong that would help me grabbing the first name, but I need all of them. There is any way to gather one by one with a foreach? Thanks.

Comment: ``IEnumerable<string> nameList = properties.Select(p=>p.Name)`` will gives all keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) for that, parse your JSON and get the name and value from the first property

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path + "/" + response));
var property = json.Properties().FirstOrDefault();
var name = property.Name;  //returns "typeOfDriver" string
var value = property.Value.ToString();
```

With your current code and deserialize to `dynamic` it can be the similar

```cs
IEnumerable<JProperty> properties = loadConfig.Properties();
var name = properties.FirstOrDefault()?.Name; //returns "typeOfDriver" string
```

To iterate all properties names you can just go through them in a `foreach` loop

```cs
foreach (var property in loadConfig.Properties())
{
    var name = property.Name;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question. With this code you wrote I think I would only be able to gather the first property name. How I could gather all of them with a foreach?

Comment: `Properties()` method returns `IEnumerable` of `JProperty` items, you can easily go through it in `foreach` loop and get every property name

Comment: Thanks, I will try that later.

Comment: Fully working, I appreacite it. Thanks @Pavel Anikhouski

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend making a class to represent the data coming from the JSON file.  If the data is dynamic, deserializing to a Dictionary might make the most sense.  If you need to traverse the JSON hierarchy, you might want to deserialize to JObject.  Anything that's not defined explicitly with Newtonsoft.Json will come back as JObject, so using dynamic isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you should be doing type-safe-ly. Something like this (don't forget to take `using NewtonSoft.Json;`):

```
public class InfoDto {
  public string typeOfDriver {get; set;}
  public string url {get; set;}
}

// get the string any way you want and then 

InfoDto myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InfoDto>(someString);

// use myObject.typeOfDriver any way you want ...
```